# How to delete undefined extension file from git?

Tags: git, undefined

I created a file accidentally with undefined extension in `GIT bash`. I have attached a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

- I tried `git rm text,txt` but that is not working .
- I can delete directly from my repository from my folder but O want to delete via git bash.

Answer (score 3):

As `text,txt` is not tracked via git (see the `git status` output)
you can delete it only via the normal `del` command (resp. `rm` on Unix systems), not via
`git rm`.

Comment: true. By the way, you're mightily active these days :) Cheers!